# Chart.js: Line chart with partial dashed line

Tags: javascript, line, chart.js

I'm trying to draw a line chart which should display a line partially solid and partially dashed (to represent real and expected data).
I've found this example that works perfectly on version 2.0.0-alpha

```js
var lineChartData = {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        data: [1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4],
        borderColor: '#66f',
        borderDash: [20, 30],
        pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
    },{
        label: "My First dataset",
        data: [1, 8, 3, 4, 2, , ],
        borderColor: '#66f',
        pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
        elements: {
            line: {
                fill: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nnnick/Chart.js/f3eb6f4a433b4f34a582842dcf7b42f710861a7d/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"/>
```

But when I run the same code with the current 2.1.3 version the lines don't overlap correctly (between points D and E):

```js
var lineChartData = {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        data: [1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4],
        borderColor: '#66f',
        borderDash: [20, 30],
        pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
    },{
        label: "My First dataset",
        data: [1, 8, 3, 4, 2, , ],
        borderColor: '#66f',
        pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
        elements: {
            line: {
                fill: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"/>
```

Unfortunately I cannot use the alpha version because of other bugs that are resolved in the current release.
Any way to replicate the graph in the first snippet with the release version?

Comment: what if you add the whole data to the dashed to...

Comment: @lolka_bolka the dashed line already has all the data points, but it doesn't overlap correctly and you can see part of it behind the solid line

Answer (score 14):

One solution may be: set values of dataset(1)  to null when it isn't visible.
This line does not create a bezier Curve, it's the inconvenience.

Example:

```
var lineChartData = {
labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    data: [, , , , 2, 3, 4],
    borderColor: '#66f',
    borderDash: [20, 30],
    pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
},{
    label: "My First dataset",
    data: [1, 8, 3, 4, 2, , ],
    borderColor: '#66f',
    pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
}]
```

};

https://jsfiddle.net/scs_3/8qqv69ot/